# How to get 3 channel image data?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to retrieve 3 channel color data from `CGImage`, but it fails in `CGContext` with the message:

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination:     7443 % 4!=
> 0; bytes per row must be a multiple of bytes per pixel

I'm running the following code:

```
// cgImage is defined
let width = cgImage.width
let height = cgImage.height
let bytesPerPixel = 3 // RGB
let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width

let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: height * bytesPerRow)

let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
    .union(.byteOrder32Little).rawValue

guard let context = CGContext(data: rawData,
                              width: width,
                              height: height,
                              bitsPerComponent: 8,
                              bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                              space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                              bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else {
    fatalError("Unable to create bitmap context.")
}
context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
```

My expectation is that `CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast` would make it ignore the alpha channel and record only 3 colors totaling 3 bytes per pixel, but apparently it is still trying to encode 4 bytes per pixel. Am I misunderstanding something? How do I get only 3 channel image data from a `CGImage`?

Comment: `noneSkipLast` still means 4 bytes per pixel, just that there is no alpha data in the 4th byte. You probably want `.none` for 3 bytes per pixel.

Comment: The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimagealphainfo)  says "There is no alpha channel". But ok, then it says "unsupported parameter combination: ... kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGImageByteOrder32Little | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked". Any suggestions how to get 3 channels, hopefully efficiently?

Comment: `.none` means 24 bit, not 32 bit. Try without adding a byte order and see what happens.

Comment: No, it says not supported. It seems I can't get 24 bits from it? I'm also looking at the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) that doesn't mention 24 bits.